# I want to create multiple users without using Laravel's default users database

Tags: laravel, database, authentication

How can I log in using a different database? I am having problems logging in with a different user and database?

##### AuthController

```
public function loginAksi(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->email == null or $request->password == null) {
        return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'Masukkan Email atau Password !']);
    } else {
        if (Auth::attempt([ 'email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password ])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if($user->level == 1){
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard')->with(['success' => 'Selamat Datang']);
            } elseif($user->level == 0){
                return redirect()->route('user');
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('userlansia');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'Login Gagal !']);
        }
    }
}
```

I have successfully used a user login from the default database such as users, now I want to log in with a different database

**Model Lansia**

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'id_lansia',
        'nama_lansia',
        'tempat_lahir',
        'tgl_lahir',
        'alamat',
        'No_tlp',
        'NIK',
        'No_BPJS',
        'email',
        'password',
        'level',
        'user'  
    ];

    protected $table = 'lansias';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_lansia';
```

**auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
```

**kernel.php**

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
      'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
      'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware::class,
      'userlansia' => \App\Http\Middleware\LansiaMiddleware::class,
];
```

can anyone help?

Comment: do you want `User` model and `Lansia` both? Or just the table name for `User` model will be different? Or do you want to switch the database on runtime?

Comment: I want both of them to be able to log in with 2 different databases. Can you help me? I hope you can explain in detail

Comment: do you want to connect multiple databases or from same database but different tables ? or  do you want to  make authentication for different users  like admin and user ?

Comment: I want to create 3 users. I have a problem where I have created an admin and a user, namely mother, but I want to create 1 more user, but it's different from the user table. I want to create 1 more user, namely Lansia.

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel, you can configure multiple database connections and authentication providers in the config/database.php and config/auth.php files respectively.

#### Setting up Multiple Database Connections:

In config/database.php, define your database connections under the connections array. For example, if you want to set up two MySQL connections:

```
'connections' => [ 'mysql' => 
[ // Your default connection configuration ], 
'mysql1' => [ 'driver' => 'mysql', // Configure your second database connection details here ], 
]
```

To use Eloquent models with different databases, specify the connection at the top of your model:

```
class MyModel extends Model { protected $connection = 'mysql1';
}
```

Setting up Authentication Providers:

In config/auth.php, define your authentication providers under the providers array. If you have different User models for each connection:

```
'providers' => ['users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'users1' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => App\Models\User1::class,
    ],
],
```

To authenticate users from a specific table, use the guard method:

```
if (Auth::guard('users1')->attempt($credentials)) {// Authentication successful for users1 table
} else {
    // Authentication failed
}
```

By following these steps, you can manage multiple database connections and authentication providers in your Laravel application.

Comment: Undefined array key "database" in controller

Comment: You do know that you are using AI to reply and it is strictrly prohibited?

Comment: I don't use AI but I use Google Translate, I have language problems

Comment: Do not roll back the changes to where it is UNREADABLE...

Comment: im sorry bro im newbie

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?